# Directus. Display Create view for two models at once. Autobind to a directus user

Tags: directus, headless-cms

I'm absolutely new to Directus. Please advice what to read to implement this. I have two models: `Application` and `ApplicationMark`.

`Application`:

- name

`ApplicationMark`

- a value of [1,2,3,4,5] // a mark of application
- application // an application that is marked
- user // a Directus user who marked the application

I want to display Application along with its ApplicationMark for the Directus user who marked it. How can I do that? What should I create? Custom layout? Custom view? Just guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to do this via GUI. Directus is amazing! In my case I needed to create a relational field one-to-many on `Application` to `ApplicationMark` and users can edit both on `Application` model view.